# Can we get rid of [database-edition] tag?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

There is this tag - [database-edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-edition). There are a total of 25 questions tagged like this.

And I don't think that this tag is useful in any way.

And on top of it - there is no tag wiki available.

Comment: Seems to be used _almost_ exclusively by Visual Studio and SQL Server users. Would be nice to get their POV here. Also the bulk of the questions seem incredibly old. Certainly seems like an ambiguous tag that needs to be renamed and not burninated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, that was a very poorly named tag that was doing nothing to categorize questions.

The tag was *probably* meant to refer to [Visual Studio Team System 2008, Database Edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365094/visual-studio-2008-database-edition-what-is-it), corroborated by the fact that most of these questions were also tagged [visual-studio-2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2008). These comprised the bulk of the roughly 25 questions using this tag.

It very likely got created by someone typing this phrase into the tag box, writing out the complete name of their software package, not understanding how tags work here on Stack Overflow. Most of these questions were unsuitable for Stack Overflow for various reasons. I have closed and/or deleted them. A handful of the questions I deemed salvageable, and I edited those into shape, removing the tag at the same time. The [visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio), [visual-studio-2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2008), and/or [vsts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsts) (which is now a synonym of [azure-devops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-devops)) tags are sufficient for these questions.

There is also [visual-studio-2008-db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2008-db), which is highly related, but according to the wiki, doesn't refer to the software package so much as the projects created with it. This tag could potentially be removed as well, but isn't causing any harm, so I'm leaving it be.

A number of other questions with this tag were about Oracle. I have no idea why. I guess Oracle once upon a time also released something called the "Database Edition". Gee, I wonder how that was different from all their other database products? Anyway, those questions have now received the same treatment: editing to salvage, or outright removal.

Finally, there were a couple of straggler questions, using the tag for completely unknown reasons. Those have been…dealt with as well.